# TypeError: $(...).on is not a function-While grouping the checked check box row values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I need help in resolving this error : "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function"

I have used the jquery function to group the set of values present in the checked check box row. The values present in the checkedRows array is not getting printed in my console,instead error is coming.Help me in printing the checked checkbox row values.

This is my jquery function in my jsp page

```
<script>
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            var checkedRows = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                checkedRows.push(
                  $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                      return $(this).html();
                  }).get()
                ); 
             });        
            console.log( checkedRows );

        });
    </script>
```

**JSP**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
        <%@page import="web.Products"%>
        <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
        <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('#btn').on('click', function() {
            var checkedRows = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                checkedRows.push(
                  $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                      return $(this).html();
                  }).get()
                ); 
             });        
            console.log( checkedRows );

        });
    </script>

    </head>
         <form name="sform" method="post" action="Save_Products"> 
          <table style="width:40%">
              <tr> <th> Brand Name</th>
                  <th> Product Name</th>
                  <th> Description</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td><%
      List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("productlist");
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
      out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"brand_name\" value=\""  + prod.getBrandname() + "\">");
          out.println("<br/>"+prod.getBrandname());

            } %> </td>
           <td><%
      if(pdts!=null){
        for(Products prod: pdts){
           out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" checked=\"checked\" value=\""  + prod.getProductname() + "\">"  + prod.getProductname()+"<br>");
            } } %> </td>
           <td><%
           if(pdts!=null){
           for(Products prod: pdts){
            out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"desc\" style=\"width:50px; height:22px\" value=\""+prod.getDesc()+"\"/><br/>");
        } 
       }  
       } %> </td>  
       </tr>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center">  <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Save" name="save"/> </td></tr> 

          </table>
             </form>
        </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to define checkedRows outside click scope / global?

Comment: Since I am using the old version of jquery 'live' function should be used instead of 'on'. The error is rectified by doing so,but the values of the checked check box rows are not getting printed in my browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of jQuery you are used? if old one try this:

```
$('#btn').live('click', function() {
            var checkedRows = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                checkedRows.push(
                  $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function() {
                      return $(this).html();
                  }).get()
                ); 
             });        
            console.log( checkedRows );

        });
```

Comment: The error is solved!  but the checkedRows values are not getting printed in my console.Is there anything wrong in my jquery function?

Comment: You want to get html of first column of row in table? if yes try this:

$('#btn').live('click', function() {
                var checkedRows = [];
                $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function() {
                    checkedRows.push(
                      $(this).find('td:first').html();
                   
                    ); 
                 });        
                console.log( checkedRows );
    
            });

Comment: I need to get the Brand Name,Product Name and Description for all the checked ProductName checkboxes